# Comparar dois arrays de objetos e remover a diferença no javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array de produtos e categorias de tamanhos variáveis. Tenho que retornar o array de categorias eliminando as categorias que não tem nenhum produto vinculado.

Categorias:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    nome: Categoria 1
},
{
   id: 2,
   nome: Categoria 2
},
{
   id: 3,
   nome: Categoria 3
}]
```

Produtos:

```
[{
    nome: Produto 1,
    category_id: 1
},
{
    nome: Produto 2,
    category_id: 2
}]
```

No exemplo acima gostaria de retornar o array de categorias retirando a Categoria 3, já que não existe nenhum produto ligado a ela.Tentei usar o filter mas não consegui remover.

```
let products = response.data;
let categories = categories.filter(function (element, index, array) {
    if (element.id !== self.products[index].category_id) {
        return element;
    }
});
```

Comment: E você precisa fazer isso pelo JavaScript? Não seria conveniente fazer isso no lado do servidor e somente entregar ao cliente as categorias que possuem produtos?

Comment: Não porque preciso das categorias completas para utilizar em outro lugar.

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema da pergunta para ser marcada como pendente.

Comment: Acredito que seja porque não apresentou a sua tentativa, apenas pediu como faz. Busque [edit] e adicionar a sua tentativa bem como descrever qual foi o resultado obtido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pequeno exemplo de filtro:

```js
const categorias = [{
    id: 1,
    nome: 'Categoria 1'
},
{
   id: 2,
   nome: 'Categoria 2'
},
{
   id: 3,
   nome: 'Categoria 3'
}];

const produtos = [{
    nome: 'Produto 1',
    category_id: 1
},
{
    nome: 'Produto 2',
    category_id: 2
}];

const categoriasFiltradas = categorias.filter(categoria => produtos.filter(produto => produto.category_id === categoria.id).length);

console.log(JSON.stringify(categoriasFiltradas));
```